# FullCalendar.js is not displaying events in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm attempting to use fullcalendar.in a ASP.NET MVC application to display events. I have loaded in some test data however it does not display within the calendar (The Calendar Displays). I have implemented some error handling with in JavaScript, and the call appears to the controller appears to be working correctly.

Also when going directly to the controller URL, the correct data is there.

Helper Class

```
    public class FCEvents
    {
    public int ID;
    public string EventTitle;
    public string StartDateString;
    public string EndDateString;


    public static List<FCEvents> LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange()
    {
        using (EventDb ev = new EventDb())
        {
            var rslt =
            from e in ev.Events
            select new EventsListViewModel
            {
                EventID = e.EventID,
                EventTitle = e.EventTitle,
                CourseCode = e.Course.CourseCode, 
                StartDate = e.StartDate,
                FinishDate = e.FinishDate,
                Location = e.Location
            };

            List<FCEvents> result = new List<FCEvents>();

            foreach (var item in rslt)
            {
                FCEvents rec = new FCEvents ();
                rec.ID = item.EventID;
                rec.EventTitle = item.EventTitle + "-" + item.CourseCode + "-" + item.Location;
                rec.StartDateString = item.StartDate.ToString("s"); 
                rec.EndDateString = item.FinishDate.ToString("s");
                result.Add(rec);
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

GetEvents Controller

```
        public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
        var elc = FCEvents.LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange();
        var EventList =
            from e in elc
            select new 
            {
                id = e.ID,
                title = e.EventTitle,
                start = e.StartDateString,
                end = e.EndDateString
            };

        var rows = elc.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JavaScript

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        GetEvents();
    });

    function GetEvents() {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev, next, today'
            },
            defaultView: 'month',
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            dataType: 'json',

            eventSources: [
                {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetEvents")',
                type: 'POST',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                success: function () {
                    alert('we got the events!');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
                },
            }],
        });
    }
</script>
```

}

This is the result form the controller:

*"[{"ID":1,"EventTitle":"FIrstAid T-\r\nHLTAID001-South Morang","StartDateString":"2015-08-14T10:00:00","EndDateString":"2015-08-15T00:00:00"},{"ID":3,"EventTitle":"First Aid F-\r\nHLTAID001-Richmond","StartDateString":"2015-08-11T02:08:00","EndDateString":"2015-08-13T00:00:00"},{"ID":4,"EventTitle":"Fire T-\r\nHLTAID001-Richmond","StartDateString":"2015-08-20T03:08:00","EndDateString":"2015-08-25T00:00:00"},{"ID":2000,"EventTitle":"Testing-\r\nHLTAID001-Mill Park","StartDateString":"2015-08-15T00:00:00","EndDateString":"2015-08-20T00:00:00"}]"*

Any help would be appreciated, I have spent the last two days coming back to this and I cannot appear to figure it out.

Just to recap, the calendar works, but no events are being displayed.

Comment: Is the action/controller actually being called when the page is loaded (i.e. when `GetEvents()` is called)? Is the `eventSources` actually working?

Comment: It appears to be, as when I change the @Url.Action to a different controller, I the then receive the error message.

Comment: having the same problem, GetEvents() isn't even called. I set a breakpoint at the first line in the method, and it doesn't hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score -1):

I have been screwing around with the same issues, so I guess I know the frustration. However, I tried the sample below, and this is working for. I don't see much difference, only the @Url.Action is giving me an error in the JavaScript

```
    eventSources: [
    {
        url: '/Agenda/GetEvents/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { userId: $('#UserId').val() },
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        success: function () {
            alert('we got the events!');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
    }
],
```

Comment: Hi Jelle, I inserted your alterations, I just swapped userId with eventId and the events still do not display in the calendar, although I'm still retrieving the 'we got the events' - do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: Did you folks get anywhere with this? I'm trying to use FullCalendar myself, but it's not calling my GetEvents method